# VIM - running a shell command fails within a macro

Tags: vim, shell, macros

I have a list of items in a file, and I am trying to add an id on the line before each one. The id is generated by an external shell command and added to the buffer:

```
:r !php _setup/getid/php item | tail -1
```

This works fine in normal mode. However, when I record a macro containing only the above command and then run it I get the error:

```
Could not open input file: _set
```

added to the buffer.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using tab completion to get the path to my script, which means the macro - literally just a recording of keystrokes - looked like gibberish.

Explicitly typing out the shell command resulted in a macro that worked.